# How to write an Ansible playbook with Docker-compose

Tags: docker, ansible

Please help, I have the docker-compose file below, and I want to write an Ansible playbook that runs the docker-compose file on localhost and a remote target.

```
   version: '2.0'

services:
weather-backend:
  build: ./backend
  volumes:    #map backend dir and package inside container
    - './backend/:/usr/src/'
    - './backend/package.json:/usr/src/package.json'
  #ports:
 #  - "9000:9000" #expose backend port - Host:container
  ports:
     - "9000:9000"
  command: npm start


weather-frontend:
  build: ./frontend
  depends_on:
    - weather-backend
  volumes:
    - './frontend/:/usr/src/'
    - '/usr/src/node_modules'
  ports:
    - "8000:8000" #expose ports -Host:container
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: "development"
```

Answer (score 19):

Since Ansible 2.1, you can have a look at the [docker_compose](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_compose_module.html#docker-compose-module), which can read directly a `docker-compose.yml`

playbook task:

```
- name: run the service defined in my_project's docker-compose.yml
  docker_compose:
    project_src: /path/to/my_project
```

Comment: This executes the `docker-compose` existing in the host running Ansible, communicating to the `docker` API in the destination host. If you want to execute docker-compose directly in the destination host, you'll need an alternate solution.

Comment: @emi I agree: I suppose https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_compose_module.html#parameter-docker_host means the local docker compose can communicate with a remote Docker.